# need to remove www from 2nd level subdomain generically in Apache (using rewrite)

Tags: apache, subdomain

I have the problem but with many subdomains: E.g..

sub1.domain.com  and new.domain.com and xsub.domain.com and many many more like this.

How do I remove the www from in front of any of these with one generic rule.

E.g. if someone types www..domain.com or http://www..domain.com to change it to

http://.domain.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use the rewrite module to remove the www. when it precedes a sub-domain. In this way, an address like:  www.sub1.domain.com would be redirected to sub1.domain.com:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified tested solution but for http only.

```
#Allow domain of the form www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.([^\..]*)\.([^\..]*)$ [NC]

#Otherwise any other form must be rewritten to remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]

#Substitue the complete domain using group %1 in the parentheses of the above condition
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, and return with http://

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R,L]
```

For https, just add the s, as so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R,L]
```

Note that this can be done in httpd.conf as well. Using .htaccess is popular but actually slows down the site, especially if there are nested directories.

You do need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

But you do not need Indexes.